# Change link attribute after calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jQuery Mobile application I have a listview that calls a function when clicked:

```
<a href="" onclick="OnSaveOrDelete(' + item.ID + ')" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Go home</a>
```

When a row link as above is clicked it calls this function:

```
function OnSaveOrDelete(acID){
    
    if (localStorage.Favourites.indexOf("/" + acID + "/") >= 0)
    {
        alert('Ac Removed #' + acID);
        $(this).prop('data-icon','delete');
        var tmp = localStorage.Favourites;
        localStorage.Favourites = tmp.replace("/" + acID + "/", "");
    }
    else{ 
            alert('New Ac Saved #' + acID);
            localStorage.Favourites += "/" + acID + "/";
        }
}
```

When the existing item isn't in localStorage I add it, and then need to change the icon / data-icon attribute. As is shown in my code above, I'm trying to do this via:

```
$(this).prop('data-icon','delete');
```

I've also tried:

```
$(this).attr('data-icon','delete');
```

But neither of these work. I'm assuming this is because '$(this)' isn't defined.

How can I updated my code to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` in:

```
onclick="OnSaveOrDelete(' + item.ID + ', this)"

function OnSaveOrDelete(acID, obj) {
    //$(obj) refers to the clicked element
    $(obj).prop('data-icon','delete');
}
```

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - What about it? That will get the native DOM element *if* `this` was defined - it wasn't.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal -- You could use it like so `this.setAttribute("data-icon", "delete");` - no need to wrap it in jQuery only to access it natively again.

Comment: Im not understanding what you're asking?

Comment: If we can't use $(this).prop() I don't think we can use this as in this.setAttribute()

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal -- You're not understanding - `$(this).prop` wasn't working in the question because `this` was undefined. Now, `$(this)[0]` references the native DOM element - which doesn't have a method called `prop` - `prop` is a jQuery method.

Comment: Yep - that'll work - altho that is the same as `this.setAttribute()`\

Comment: what about using like this? $($(this)[0]).prop() ?

Comment: just willing to know only, will not implement anyway, anytime.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try in the morning

Comment: @tymeJV Resolved it now. It needed a different attribute call eg: $(obj).buttonMarkup({ icon: "delete" });